# In Google Sheets get first n results from an array without using query

Tags: google-sheets, statistics, google-sheets-query

I have a table:

[image]

The formula in `W.Avg. Value per Point` for size "Small" is this:

```
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(
  FILTER(
    INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_sdcalcs_size"),0,2),
    INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_listings"),0,3) = H15,
    INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_sdcalcs_size"),0,2)<>""
  ),
  FILTER(
    INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_listings"),0,5),
    INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_listings"),0,3) = H15,
    INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_sdcalcs_size"),0,2)<>""
  )
)
```

Where `H15` = "Small".

This formula works... It will lookup all defined values and weights for "Small" listings on another sheet and give me a weighted average of those values. The problem is that the sample array of values and weights returned by the two FILTER() functions are not representative of the population of *glows*.

I know the population distribution of glows (`% Chance` under `Glows`). From this I have created the following table:

[image]

This gives me a representative count for each glow relative to each size (and vice versa). And, again, everything to this point is working just fine.

But the final step is where I'm struggling. When I lookup size "Small" values in the FILTER() functions above I need to limit the results returned to AVERAGE.WEIGHTED() to (in this example) 62 none, 31 Dusky, 15 Lucent, 7 Bright, 3 Brilliant, 1 Radiant, and none of Dazzling, StarLike, Crown Jewel, or Titanic. As per the "Small" row in the second image.

The spreadsheet this is all from is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQ19xHirBs57_vn2dTdfEabf47gyh4sxeIe_aigsMfk/edit?usp=sharing#gid=1185238593).

I actually achieved this already using QUERY()'s "limit" feature. Unfortunately using QUERY() anywhere in the spreadsheet makes the (unrelated) Google Apps scripts go from taking ~10 seconds to execute to taking ~200 seconds to execute. This makes QUERY() unusable in my case. Here's what I had for that (doesn't actually work, see comments):

```
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(
  FILTER(
    ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
      INDIRECT("recent_data"),
      "select ( E * F ) where (
        D = '"&$H$27:$H$36&"' and
        C = '"&$H15&"' and
        V > 0
      ) limit "&$C46:$L46
    )),
    ISNUMBER(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
      INDIRECT("recent_data"),
      "select ( E * F ) where (
        D = '"&$H$27:$H$36&"' and
        C = '"&$H15&"' and
        V > 0
      ) limit "&$C46:$L46
    )))
  ),
  FILTER(
    ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
      INDIRECT("recent_data"),
      "select F where (
        D = '"&$H$27:$H$36&"' and
        C = '"&$H15&"' and
        V > 0
      ) limit "&$C46:$L46
    )),
    ISNUMBER(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
      INDIRECT("recent_data"),
      "select F where (
        D = '"&$H$27:$H$36&"' and
        C = '"&$H15&"' and
        V > 0
      ) limit "&$C46:$L46
    )))
  )
)
```

I also tried to use SORTN(). But that's not going to work for a number of reasons.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(FILTER(
  INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_sdcalcs_size"),0,2),
  INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_listings"),0,3) = H15,
  INDEX(INDIRECT("recent_sdcalcs_size"),0,2)<>""
),TRANSPOSE($C46:$L46)))
```

Comment: Regarding INDIRECT(): to deal with a known bug in Sheets. When the named ranges are resized via Apps Scripts google goes and changes every reference to those named ranges to `#REF!` breaking the formula. And (because the number of rows on the sheet this pulls data from isn't static) I have a script that resizes that sheet and the named ranges on it every so often to keep from having hundreds of blank rows that slow down my formulas.

Comment: As for the QUERY(): it works, almost. Needed a bit more tweaking to get exactly what I wanted. But, as I said, if the spreadsheet contains a QUERY() function in *any* cell the Apps Scripts associated with that spreadsheet suddenly take 20x as long to run. Even when the apps scripts aren't accessing that cell or any affected by it. This appears to be another bug in Google Sheets.

Comment: I can check again... wrapping `QUERY()` in `ARRAYFORMULA()` should, essentially, run the query once for each item in array H27:H36 and C46:L46 (10 times total, think of it like a for..in loop). But I don't think it matters if `QUERY()` was working or not... as I can't use `QUERY()` for this due to other problems. And, unfortunately, `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN()` is one of a few functions I can't use with `ARRAFORMULA()`. A rule of thumb is if a function takes arrays as input (and it's not a lookup function), it can't be used with `ARRAYFORMULA()`.

Comment: Whelp, @I'-'I is correct, apparently, `QUERY()` also doesn't work with `ARRAYFORMULA()`... yet another reason I can't use it for this.

Comment: I'm certain that it always happens when the above `QUERY()` is in the sheet in any cells under the `W.Avg. Value per Point`, `Median Value`, or `Kept Data Points` columns. What I'm seeing is all the getNamedRange() calls in my apps script go from taking a fraction of a second each to each taking >5 seconds. This includes `getNamedRage()` calls for ranges that are neither referenced by nor affected by the cells in question. And the affected functions take >20x as long to execute completely. And I'm certain it doesn't happen when there are no `QUERY()` functions anywhere in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I could write a script and put it on a timer event. But it's not as performant as native sheets functions unless I do large swaths of data all in one go (which I could do). That's my fall back/last resort if there's no other way. I suppose I should do some more tests with query() to nail down the exact parameters that will cause the slow execution. I'll do that this afternoon.